# Excel Formula to determine a maximum series pattern

Tags: google-sheets

I have an Excel representing a Major League Baseball Season
Rows represent Games Played (In Order #1 to #162)

Columns represent each Team

Cells display a W (win) or L (loss)

At the bottom of each Column (for each Team) I need three results :

1. Maximum # of W's in a row for this Column (Team)
2. Maximum # of L's in a row for this Column (Team)
3. Maximum # of alternating Win/Loss or WL in a row for this Column (Team)

The last one may need a better explanation :
heres an example Team A has these cells in order :
WWWLLWLWL**LWLWLWL**LLWWLW  --- the answer here is 7 as the maximum streak of alternating results is 7

Comment: I think I 've seen this with a formula; I may be wrong but if I did, it was overly complex. Better to design a simple 10 line VBA [tag:user-defined-functions].

Comment: this actually a Google Sheet

Comment: Goodbye and good luck with your project! [tag:javascript] handles arrays created from splits just as easily as [tag:vba] does.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i have no idea where to start!

Comment: Looks similar to this https://exceljet.net/formula/longest-winning-streak if you can convert your input data to T/F series for "same as/different from next letter"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function countPairs() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var s=ss.getActiveSheet()
  var lr=s.getLastRow()
  var lc=s.getLastColumn()
  for(var j=1;j<lc+1;j++){
      var range= s.getRange(2, j, lr-1,1).getValues()
      var count=0
      var maxwl=0
      for(var i=161;i>0;i--){
         if(range[i][0]!=range[i-1][0]){
             count=count+1 
         if(count>maxwl){maxwl=count}
    }
    else{count=0}   
  }
  max=maxwl+1
  s.getRange(167,j).setValue(max)
  }}
```

Here is a test spreadsheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z_YpKNtk7nVKCOHyVcRC8sxN0GGxqQ8axdi1_UYUwgI/edit?usp=sharing

I fixed the pairs count and changed the W and L count formulas to max. I also added a custom menu to run the script. To use the script, from the sheet menu, select tools and open the script editor. Delete what is there and copy and paste the code from the script editor of the sample spreadsheet. Save it then run it. You will be asked to approve it.

Comment: omg this is so close! first thing is i am not sure where to put this code? second in your example ... i dont really want the SUM of W or L but the MAX Ws in sequence per column and MAX Ls in a sequence per column... also the streak highlight is one MORE than the number in the bottom cell .........cant wait to vote this UP

Comment: Thx Ed! I am super close! I got the max formulas into my sheet - i had to add ONE to each of them to calc it right - thank you! .... i am ver new to Google Sheets . I added the code above to Tools / Script Editor, tried to save and then went into a whole thing about approving an app? I just want to run this on my spreadsheet and place the results in the bottom cells? i dont see how to : 1) save the script in this spreadsheet 2) run the script and have it place into the bottom cells?

Comment: Just Google how to run Google Apps Script. You can even find you-tube on how to do it.

Comment: Ed - got it all working - thank you - i did upvote but would not appear publicly until i get a reputation

Comment: Glad you got it working. I believe you can approve the answer by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer. That should also give you points.